# What is the interpretation of the expectation notation in the GAN formulation?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, statistics, generative-models

I'm confused about the expectation notation in the context of GAN loss functions.

The GAN loss for the discriminator is binary cross-entropy. ie: is this real or not.

real = $D(x)$ (ie: give the discriminator a real image)
fake = $D(G(z))$  (ie: generate a fake image and ask discriminator what it is)

Then the binary crossentropy is:
$$log(p) - log (1-p)$$

When used as a GAN loss we replace p with either "real class" or "fake class".

$$log(real) - log (1-fake)=\\
log(D(x)) - log (1-D(G(z)))$$

So far, this is ok (i think haha).

But the actual formulation adds an expectation sign... which I don't understand why it's there.

$$E_{x~data}log(D(x)) - E_z log (1-D(G(z)))$$

Answer (score 3):

The functions $$ L_a(x) = \log(D(x))\;\;\;\;\&\;\;\;\; L_b(z) = \log(1-D(G(z))) $$
are defined for *one value* (either $x$ or $z$).

We don't want to optimize $L_a$ or $L_b$ for *one input*, we want to minimize it for *all possible* inputs $x$ and $z$. Suppose $x\in X\equiv\mathbb{R}^n$ (e.g., by "unfolding" it as an image) and $z\in Z\equiv \mathbb{R}^m$. Then we can write minimizing over all possible inputs as minimizing $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} L_a(x)\,dx $ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}^m} L_b(z)\, dz$. But there's something wrong with this! In fact, we don't care about, say, pure red images or electron microscope micrographs (if $x$ were images), we only care about "real" photographs, i.e., the "natural images". So instead of optimizing over *all* $X$ and $Z$, we prefer to optimize over the ones that "matter". We do this by placing a probability distribution on $X$ and $Z$, say $P_x$ and $P_z$, such that sampling from these distributions gives us the $x$ and $z$ values that we care about. Low probability is given to unnatural images $x$; high probability is given to e.g. images of dogs and cats.
For GANs, we often choose $P_z$ in advance, as a uniform or normal distribution.
(Some people prefer to say that the natural images form a manifold in high-dimensional space; this $P_x$ can be thought of as inducing that structure.)

But how to optimize over these "likely" images. The obvious thing to do is optimize the *expected value* over these densities. In other words, we want to optimize the values of $L_a$ and $L_b$ that we *expect* to get if we compute them on samples drawn from $P_x$ and $P_z$. This is a *weighted average* over all of data space, where the weight is given by the probability of seeing that data point:
$$
\mathbb{E}_{x\sim P_x}[L_a(x)] = \int_X L_a(x) p_x(x)\, dx
\;\;\;\;\&\;\;\;\;
\mathbb{E}_{z\sim P_z}[L_b(z)] = \int_Z L_b(z) p_z(z)\, dz
$$
where this integral (expectation) is approximated by a sum or average over a minibatch in practice.

In summary, we add the expectations because we care about how we do across all "important" $x$ and $z$ values, not just one.

The explanation in [this post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/49232/understanding-notation-of-goodfellows-gan-objective-function) might also be of use.